# Using Terms in Search Result Display Template

Tags: search, search-results, term-store, display-template, term-set

I'm writing a custom Result Type Display Template and I would like to display an item's term set in a `<ul>` list.

The `ctx.CurrentItem` contains the managed property

```
{
    'terms': "GP0|#88e40baa-2a5f-4d82-aee2-9dc4b9eda0bb;L0|#088e40baa-2a5f-4d82-aee2-9dc4b9eda0bb|Oracle;GTSet|#3a86ee05-6326-4427-a32c-bbdbd1095838;GPP|#2aa37c99-7b70-4451-9e0c-6696e5f1dfbb;GPP|#8d7d3f14-d5b7-4c03-8186-3fa785257cf4;GP0|#6a4ca799-9e1a-4252-9857-79a618df7915;L0|#06a4ca799-9e1a-4252-9857-79a618df7915|SVN;GP0|#3aabcf1e-bfaf-4664-bef4-6cb973a975ea;L0|#03aabcf1e-bfaf-4664-bef4-6cb973a975ea|PL/SQL;GPP|#463e11ac-44e1-4f22-b7c9-bf048d99fe23;GPP|#4e9d946c-32d6-46cc-8f85-48900c03ec76;GPP|#22b3827b-cbc2-449d-b727-7efede5190cf",
}
```

As you can see that term set is actually a piped string of GUIDs which (I'm guessing) represent the terms that are assigned to the item.

Is there a way to retrieve these terms (actually, their name) from either the original object or through an API call?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good approach here:
http://www.novolocus.com/2013/12/13/get-the-text-out-of-a-managed-metadata-search-property/

Comment: The links is no more valid and seems to have migrated here : http://andrewwburns.com/2013/12/13/get-the-text-out-of-a-managed-metadata-search-property/